Trying to photocopy printed music. The music lines miss
I tried to change the settings for printing the music but it didn't work.  All my cartridges are full except the PGBK is low.  I was trying to disable it.  If I set the preferences on the computer, the printer asks for something different. I don't know what I'm doing?

Welcome to Superuser. Your question, as it is currently written, is missing lots of important information. Here are some questions I have. Please answer these by adding information to the main question. Keep in mind that we need as full and accurate a description of the entire problem as you are able to give us, and we need a record of any research you have done and things you have tried, and it all needs to be clear. What didn't work? How did it not work? What was the actual output? What does "the music lines miss" mean? You were trying to disable what? What is the printer asking for?

To help get an answer can you [edit] the question to include more details. E.g. a) What printer model is being used? b) What does the printer ask for when you set the preferences on the computer?

And, while editing your question for clarity as requested above, make sure to fix the title: This is about printing, not photocopying.
